# Given a Master-detail relationship use apex loop through child records?

Tags: apex, soql

If i have a master-detail relationship with a "Classroom" and a "Student" Object. Say the master object is a classroom and the child objects are students. How do i aggregate a list of the student's names in apex given the following model?

#### Classroom__c Object

- Name
- Id
- Subject

#### Student__c Object

- Name
- Id
- Phone number
- Email

Would one just utilize soql? Or just a trigger and update a field record?

I would like to aggregate the students names into a list for an email alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Student__c> studentList = [SELECT Name, Classroom__r.id FROM Student__c WHERE Classroom__r.id =: yourClassroomId];
List<String> studentNames = new List<String>();
for (Student__c s : studentList){
  studentNames.add(s.Name);
}
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex6_3.htm

Comment: You're missing a for loop and you can't assign query results to `List<String>`.